# Saving SSIS package to local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Right now I'm able to upload an SSIS package from my local computer to SQL Server with my C# program:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();


string pkg = @"C:\Temp\myPackage.dtsx";
Package loadedPkg = app.LoadPackage(pkg, null);

app.SaveToSqlServerAs(loadedPkg, null, "myNewPackage", "myServer", null, null);
```

This works great. Now I want to do the opposite of this, save an SSIS package from the SQL Server to my local computer. I'm using the Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application?view=sqlserver-2017

It doesn't seem to have any methods to save to a computer. I see the "load" methods, but I haven't been able to get those to work. I think they just prep a package to be uploaded to the server, like in my previous example. Is this possible through the same "Application" class?

**edit**: For anyone reading this in the future: the "pkgIn" path from @Hadi's answer already has "MSDB" built into the path, so if you need "\MSDB\packages" or whatever, just use "\packages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SaveToXml()` Function to achieve that.

```
app.SaveToXml("C:\Temp\myNewPackage.dtsx", pkg, null);
```

You can refer to this link:

- [Application.SaveToXml(String, Package, IDTSEvents) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.savetoxml?view=sqlserver-2017)

---

## Update 1

Try using a similar code:

```
Package pkgIn = new Package();  
pkgIn = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\myNewPackage", "yourserver", null, null, null);
app.SaveToXml("C:\Temp\myNewPackage.dtsx", pkgIn , null);
```

You can refer to this link for more information about loading package from SQL Server:

- [Application.LoadFromSqlServer(String, String, String, String, IDTSEvents) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.loadfromsqlserver?view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_Application_LoadFromSqlServer_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_IDTSEvents_)

Comment: The "pkg" path is on the local computer, so I can set that to C:\Temp. So where do you provide the server path? For example if I want to save from \MSDB\Custom Packages\

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you asking how to save the package on local machine. Or how to load it from SQL Server??

Comment: I have a package on a SQL Server. I want to save it (export) to my local machine.

Comment: Then you should use the method i provided

Comment: The first argument is the destination path

Comment: If you need to export it to `C:\Temp` then you should pass `C:\Temp\myNewPackage.dtsx`

Comment: @coinbird i am waiting for your reply

Comment: It says  Failed to open package file "C:\Temp\newPackage.dtsx" due to error 0x800C0006 "The system cannot locate the object specified."

I'm not sure that method is right, it doesn't have a parameter for a SQL Server. Or a path in Integration Services. How does it even know where to look for the package I want to save?

Comment: The error you provided is thrown during Package Load not Package saving!!

Comment: Right, because the package does not exist at that C:\Temp location. It's on the SQL Server. I updated my post with the code you suggested.

Comment: @coinbird The code you provided is trying to open the package `C:\Temp\newPackage.dtsx` and save it to `TestPackage`

Comment: To load package from SQL Server follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.loadfromsqlserver?view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_Application_LoadFromSqlServer_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_IDTSEvents_

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: the "pkgIn" path already has "MSDB" built into the path, so if you need "\MSDB\packages" or whatever, just use "\packages"